# Calculating percentage gain on investment with regular deposits

Tags: finance, percentages

On 1st of January I had a total of 120 dollars invested in a scheme. I made further deposits (as per table below) and have a final figure of $620 on June 10th. How do I work out my percentage gain from January 1st to June 10th inclusive of the deposits made?

[image]

Comment: Surely its not that simple. These gains are weighted are they not? For example the gain from Jan 01 to Feb 05 is 25%, between Feb 05 and Apr 12 is 12.5% and between Apr 12 and Jun 10 it is about 7% ...

Comment: I note a couple of responses to my question were deleted ...

Comment: Spreadsheets have an IRR function which will calculate the internal rate of return per period for a set of cash flows.  Do you want an overall percentage return or a return per month?

Comment: I'm after an overall percentage thanks.

Comment: I recommend using a modified-Dietz relative to an overall yearly period: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Dietz_method

Answer (score 1):

There are actually multiple return calculations.

Time Weighted Return:
This is used if we precisely know the returns of each period.  When the cashflows come in, they happen at the join between the different periods.  This is the standard calculation used by professional money managers that have daily accounting of their investment returns.

Returns for each period are calculated independently $\frac {B - F - A}{A}$

$B$ is the ending balance
$F$ is the cash flow
$A$ is the beginning balance

Cash flows come in on the end of period dates.

If the flows are credited at beginning of period, returns for each period are $\frac {B -F - A}{A+F}$

The periodic returns are geometrically linked.

$(1 + \frac {400-250 - 120}{120})(1+\frac {580-130-400}{400})(1+\frac{620-580}{580})\\
\left(1+\frac {30}{120}\right)\left(1+\frac{50}{400}\right)\left(1+\frac{40}{580}\right)-1\\
\left(\frac {150}{120}\right)\left(\frac{450}{400}\right)\left(\frac{620}{580}\right)-1$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-weighted_return

Modified Dietz:

Modified Dietz is a simple interest rate of return, for investment portfolios with intermediate cash flows and no intermediate valuation:

$\frac {B-A-F}{A + \sum_\limits{t= 1}^T W_tF_t}$

$F$ is the total flow

$F_t$ are the cash flows received at time $t.$

$W_i$ is a time weighting factor for each cash flow.

Deposit $\$120$  on day 0, (invested for 160 days)

$\$250$ on day 35 (invested for 125 days)

$\$130$ on day 101 (invested for 59 days)

$\frac {620-120-250-130}{120 + 250\frac {125}{160}+130\frac{59}{160}} = 0.33\%$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Dietz_method

Another calculation is the dollar weighted return.

This method also ignores the intermediate marks to market, and plugs all of the cash flows into the IRR formula and solves for a discount rate such that the future value equals the future value.

$\sum_\limits{t = 1}^T F_t(1+r)^t = FV\\
120 (1+r)^{\frac{160}{365}}+ 250(1+r)^{\frac{125}{365}}+130(1+r)^{\frac{59}{365}} = 620$

You may see this written with present values instead of future values.

$\sum_\limits{t = 1}^T \frac{t_i}{(1+r)^t_i} = \frac{FV}{(1+r)^T}$

We cannot solve for $r$ algebraically, but we can use numerical estimates to find

$r = 95.1\%$

This is an annualized return for $r$ vs. a holding period return for the other methods.

https://breakingdownfinance.com/finance-topics/finance-basics/dollar-weighted-return/

Comment: This calculation says nothing about time.  The first gain was in one month, the others took two months each.

Comment: No, it doesn't.   Nonetheless, this is what the industry refers to as the time-weighted return.

Comment: @DougM Interesting. So according to your calculations I've made a 50% gain. I don't understand why time is not considered

Comment: @DougM Thanks for introducing me to TWR! Some interesting reading ahead.

Comment: @DougM This can't be right. How can my gain be 50%?

Comment: The time weighted calculation says that it doesn't matter how much money you had invested in any time period, you would earn the same return on those invested dollars.   You  had a 25% return in the first period, a 12.% return in the second period and a 6.9% return in the third period.   Your investment performance then is compounded over these three periods giving 50.3%

Comment: @DougM Thanks for replying. Can you please advise why your modified dietz calculations return 33% while S Spring below quotes 27.35% and 27.91%? It seems to me like there is no hard and fast way of calculating what I'm after :-(

Comment: As Mr. Spring has not provided his calculations, I cannot comment on his work.

Answer (score 1):

Well, consider an average-daily-deposit-withdrawal-balance of the year-to-date but, of course, year-to-date starts over at the end of each year. Then the software that I develop results in 27.35% . However the software projects the balance averaging as to year-end and that reduces shocks from large deposits or withdrawals.

Or for viewpoint, just average the given balances as they are:

120 for 35 days, 370 for 66 days, and 500 for 58 days.

Then the average balance is 360.125. The percentage gain is 120 / 360.125 or 33.32% .

I can very nearly match the software by projecting the current average balance to the future year-end like this:

120 for 365 days, 250 for 330 days, and 130 for 264 days.

Then the average balance projected to the future year-end is 440.05 . The percentage gain projected to the future year-end is 120 / 440.05 or 27.27%.

In either case I may be a day or two off in the calendar day counting.

Since I didn't stop at the first paragraph, I had to edit for a couple of days.

And here is a link to a modified-Dietz:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Dietz_method

Comment: OK, I'm confused. Can you please see DougM's answer above? What do you make of this?

Comment: The link I gave also links to IRR and TWR.